# OpenGL - Reading cursor position correctly but cant draw line from it

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

Im having problem with OpenGL tutorial in C++. I try to draw lines on mouse click where one edge is 0.0 and second is cursor position. When I set values manually it draws correctly but when I use variables that represent cursor's position it doesnt draw at all.

This is my callback function where I read cursor's position.

```
GLfloat x;
GLfloat y;

static void cursor_position_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xpos, double ypos) {
    x = xpos / (1024 / 2) - 1.0;
    y = ypos / (768 / 2) - 1.0;
}
```

This is where I pass the variables to draw

```
do{
    // Calculate position
    static GLfloat g_vertex_buffer_data[] = { 
        //0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f <------ THIS WORKS
        x, y, 0.0f
     };

    std::cout << x << " " << y << std::endl;

    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_vertex_buffer_data), g_vertex_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    ...

    // Draw the triangle !
    // if mouse clicked
    if (glfwGetMouseButton(window, GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_LEFT) == GLFW_PRESS) {
        glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, 2); 
    }
```

I will appreciate any help!

Comment: I think you will need to provide us with more information. What are the output values of your calculated `x` and `y` variables? Where do you call your `cursor_position_callback` ?

Comment: Are you calling `glfwPollEvents()` in the loop, and did you call `glfwSetCursorPosCallback(window, cursor_position_callback)` before the loop?

You need both if you want your `cursor_position_callback` to be called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array `g_vertex_buffer_data` is **`static`**, so the data is initialized only once and keeps its static values for all the time.
Since `x` respectively `y` are not initialized, the data in the array are set by the arbitrary random values of `x` and `y` at the begin of the program.

> ```cpp
> static GLfloat g_vertex_buffer_data[] = { 
>        //0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f <------ THIS WORKS
>        x, y, 0.0f
>     };
> ```

Use a local non static array and initialize `x` and `y` to solve the issue:

```cpp
GLfloat x = 0.0f;
GLfloat y = 0.0f;
```

```cpp
do{
    // Calculate position
    GLfloat g_vertex_buffer_data[] = { 
        //0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f <------ THIS WORKS
        x, y, 0.0f
    };

    // [...]
```

Note the local variable is set in every iteration of the loop by the current values  of `x` and `y`.

An alternative solution would be to create the array before the loop, but to change the values of the array elements in the loop:

```cpp
GLfloat g_vertex_buffer_data[] = { 
    0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f
};

do
{
    g_vertex_buffer_data[0] = x;
    g_vertex_buffer_data[1] = y;

    // [...]
```